# Как перенести из Figma в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, figma

Пишу desktop приложение на python с помощью библиотеки PyQt5.
Сделал дизайн программы в Figma.
Можно этот дизайн подключить к python коду приложения?

Comment: QLabel l; l.setPixmap("figma.png"); l.show();

Answer (score 0):

Существует 2 варианта решения данной проблемы:

1. Во вкладке `Inspect` можно копировать CSS-свойства каждого компонента и переносить их в код, добавляя атрибуты стиля через `setStylesheet`.

[image: Вкладка inspect]

2. Экспортировать каждый из элементов в SVG или PNG формате, после чего присваивая каждому из элементов картинки в качестве заднего фона.

Конечно же, лучше пользоваться первым вариантом. CSS занимает намного меньше места.